# Locking the Landscape Mode in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

I am using this code to lock the landscape mode for my iOS application.

```
#pragma mark Orientation handling

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

It is working fine in iPhone but it is not working correctly in iPad. It does not lock the landscape mode.

Need some guidance on  this.

Comment: You could also just set the orientations from the summary tab in Xcode for your app.

Comment: Some of my screens I need them to be in landscape mode. That is why I am doing it programmatically...

Comment: What is the result you are having? Is it auto rotating?

Comment: it is auto-rotating for the iPad version...

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation. Is it firing?

Comment: Do a test inside your shouldAutorotate to check for the current rotation and return NO

Comment: no.. it is not firing...

Comment: iOS6 uses shouldAutorotate. Test for the current rotation and return NO when appropriate.

Comment: it is weird, it is working for iPhone but not iPad...

Answer (score 1):

This code is incorrect:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown);
}
```

A `UIInterfaceOrientation` is not a `UIInterfaceOrientationMask`. Try something like this instead:

```
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
```

That being said, if you are trying to lock your application into **landscape** mode, there are multiple other issues here — for instance, your `supportedInterfaceOrientations` lists only portrait modes, not landscape!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally just set it in the summary tab as the comment says. If you really want to do this in code, this is only available in whatever you set as the rootViewController in your AppDelegate class.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6 I use:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

If you have a NavigationController you can add the method to a Category.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
           interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```